# Subreport is executing the Detail_Format two full times

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-reports

I am working on a genealogy database with children, parents, grandparents, etc. The one report giving trouble has the typical Report Header and Footer with a detail section in the middle, and the subreport giving trouble is in the Report Footer.

VBA code in the subreport of the Detail_Format is to determine which person in the family is displayed and how they are formatted. In nearly every case, the last person in the family is hidden so the Detail.Visible has been set to false. The problem is when running the report, the first person is also hidden.

Adding a line counter to the detail section I found that the query results were running a full two times. On the second iteration, the first person in the list is hidden because txtPrevGen still holds the value of the last person in the query from the first result set.

```
txtCount.ControlSource = "=1"  
txtCount.RunningSum = "Over Group"
```

VBA code for the Detail_Format in the subreport:

```
    Debug.Print txtCount
    
    If Nb(txtPrevGen, 0) > 3 Then
        Detail.Visible = False
    Else
        txtPerson = DLookup("fldFirstName & ' ' & fldLastName", "tblPeople", "fldID = " & txtPersonID)
    End If
    
    txtPrevGen = txtGeneration
```

If there are 4 records in the query, the debug results are:

1
2
3
4
1
2
3
4

There is no other place to indicate this subreport is being called or fired multiple times. So how can the query results re-run a second time starting from the first record?

Comment: I have a report that ran code 4 times when rendering. Never did figure out what about report design caused that but the report rendered correctly. Do you get any error? Is the report rendered correctly? If so, what is the issue?

Comment: There is no error, but does not render correctly. The problem is the first row will disappear when the dataset iterates through a second time because of the conditional formatting in the VBA code.

Comment: Why are you using VBA to pull this data anyway? Why not DLookup expression in textbox or joining tables? If still need help, suggest posting to a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: I changed gears slightly and reworked the SQL to have a more refined result set (which I didn't think was possible at first). So things have improved but the base problem still exists. Another area is counting the number of children and the result was double as the subreport was run through twice. I haven't figured out the root problem but will update if I figure it out.

Comment: Do you have a report header? And if so, does the source for that header return more than 1 row?

Comment: Tested both the Header and Footer, and each section only runs once. No repeating.